# Concerning Gentiles

Tags: talmud-gemara

Is this quote real?

Simeon Haddarsen, fol. 56-D:

> **When the Messiah comes every Jew will have 2800 Gentile slaves**

i think it is very hard to refute, becuase another chapter says so:

Eruvin 43b

> קָא סָלְקָא דַּעְתָּךְ מִדְּאֵלִיָּהוּ לָא אֲתָא, מָשִׁיחַ נָמֵי לָא
> אָתֵי, בְּמַעֲלֵי שַׁבְּתָא לִישְׁתְּרֵי! אֵלִיָּהוּ לָא אָתֵי,
> מָשִׁיחַ אָתֵי. דְּכֵיוָן דְּאָתֵי מְשִׁיחָא — הַכֹּל עֲבָדִים הֵן
> לְיִשְׂרָאֵל.
>
> The Gemara comments: It might enter your mind to say that since Elijah
> will not come on Shabbat eve due to the trouble involved, the Messiah
> will also not come then, and if so, on Shabbat eve he should also be
> permitted to drink wine. However, this reasoning is rejected: It is
> only Elijah who will not arrive on Shabbat eve, but the Messiah
> himself may arrive, **for once the Messiah comes, all the nations will
> be subservient to the Jewish people, and they will help them prepare
> whatever is needed for Shabbat.**

Comment: Where did you get that quote from?

Comment: @user6591 it from video in youtube asking jews abou gentiles, someone comment that quote

Comment: No, sorry it's not.

Comment: Perhaps link the video? If it's anti-Semitic propaganda it would make a difference. Also if he stated an actual source, it is incomplete as presented here.

Comment: @user6591: [Link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Ji_Y7YEbKY).

Comment: @Lucian That is not the video mentioned by the OP. That video is about taking a passuk in the Torah out of context and interviewing the am haaratzim who don't understand it.

Comment: *Simeon Haddarsen* would appear to be [Simeon haDarshan](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/13687), better known as [Simeon Kayyara](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simeon_Kayyara), author of the [Halachot Gedolot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halachot_Gedolot).

Comment: @Tyler I hope you're being sarcastic there.

Comment: It seems that the quote is found in Yalkut Shimoni on Nach Remez 499, which states: ובאים כלם ונופלים על פניהם לפני משיח ולפני ישראל ואומרים נהיה לך ולישראל לעבדים, וכל אחד מישראל אלפים ותת עבדים יהיו לו, שנאמר בימים ההמה אשר יחזיקו עשר אנשים מכל לשונות הגוים והחזיקו בכנף איש יהודי לאמר נלכה עמכם כי שמענו אלקים עמכם.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ArtScroll Eruvin 43b1 note 8 explains this citing *Ben Yehoyda*. In the translation of the gemara, the bolded text is the translation of the gemara while the unbolded text explains the meaning.

> **because as soon as the Messiah arrives**, all the world will recognize Israel as the chosen people and **they will all be servants
> to Israel** <sup>8</sup>

My comment: not slaves, servants are voluntary as with a job or volunteering for a soup kitchen. That is, seeing that the Jews will be trying to get ready for Shabbos while at the same time greeting the Messiah, the Nations of the world will volunteer to help them prepare.

> <sup>8</sup> The Gemara does not mean that the nations will be forced
> to work for the Jewish people, but rather that their realization of
> the true status of the Jewish nation will cause them to do so
> voluntarily (*Ben Yehoyada*)

Answer (score 4):

Denounced as pure antisemitic propaganda:

https://www.nytimes.com/2003/11/30/books/chapters/never-again.html

> Muslim student groups at the University of California's Berkeley and San Diego campuses posted flyers featuring bogus anti-Semitic quotations from the Talmud, including statements such as "A Gentile girl who is three years old can be violated" and "When the Messiah comes, every Jew will have 2800 slaves."

Answer (score 2):

These quotes are all variations of the basic quote in the Bible, that when the Messiah comes all the non-Jews will want to be Jewish (because they will see all the benefits) and will do whatever they think will get them there, without any coercion:

> Thus said the Lord of hosts: In those days, it shall come to pass that ten men shall take hold, out of all the languages of the nations, shall even take hold of the skirt of him that is a Jew, saying: We will go with you, for we have heard that God is with you.' [Zechariah 8:23]

Where does it say that anybody will be forced to do anything?

Comment: I was equally unaware that Judaism is reduced to the written Torah alone; to my knowledge, (most) Jews aren't Protestants, to hold to [Sola Scriptura](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sola_scriptura).

Answer (score 1):

It may be a reference to the following Talmudic passage:

> אמר ריש לקיש כל הזהיר בציצית זוכה ומשמשין לו שני אלפים ושמונה מאות עבדים שנאמר כה אמר ה׳ [צבאות] בימים ההמה אשר יחזיקו עשרה אנשים מכל לשנות הגוים [והחזיקו] בכנף איש יהודי לאמר נלכה עמכם וגו׳
>
> Resh Lakish said: He who is observant of fringes will be privileged to be served by two thousand eight hundred slaves, for it is said, Thus saith the Lord of hosts: In those days it shall come to pass, that ten men shall take hold, out of all the languages of the nations shall even take hold of the skirt of him that is a Jew, saying, We will go with you, etc.
>
> (Shabbat 32b, Soncino translation)

Comment: I think this answer would do well to better highlight the differences between the quote and this passage

Comment: Those who beg to be the servants of the Jew will then be converted to Judaism which is their stated goal.

Comment: This answer is misleading and can be used as reference for anti-semitic propaganda

Comment: Upvoted for providing relevant (re)sources.

Comment: @kouty So wait, you downvote the best answer to this question because it can be an anti-semitic reference point? Your profile says, "Try to be involved in learning". How can we if you subvert the truth?

Comment: @kouty What is your agenda here?

Comment: I didn't downvote